# Nextjs export gives Cannot find module for page

Tags: next.js

Hi I just started playing around with nextjs to see if it fits my use case. I wanted to export the site with some dynamic routes.

My pages folder structure is like below

```
page
  locales
    [locale]
      [slug].js
```

When I run `next develop` I can access the page at `http://localhost:3000/locales/de-DE/summer-dress-f`.

So now im trying to export the page with `next.config.js` like

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      "/locales/de-DE/summer-dress-f": {
        page: "/locales",
        query: { locale: "de-DE", slug: "summer-dress-f" }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

`next build` runs fine but when I run `next export` I get the error

```
Error: Cannot find module for page: /locales
    at pageNotFoundError (/Users/bmathew/Desktop/workspace/next-demo/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/require.js:13:17)
```

Any ideas what am I missing here?

Comment: it works fine for me with the latest version with your provided config, I think it's something else going on for your app. Which version of next.js are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The pathmap should look like

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      "/locales/de-DE/summer-dress-f": {
        page: "/locales/[locale]/[slug]",
        query: { locale: "de-DE", slug: "summer-dress-f" }
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes the problem happens when we are building and we have another terminal running **yarn dev**

Comment: This is an interesting insight. I was trying to hit my own API via localhost which is required by some processes while building the site via getStaticProps. After switching to calling our production API (assume I stopped calling localhost:3000/API and started calling mysite.com/API) the build process was successful.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. I had yarn dev running on the same project in another tab.

Answer (score 15):

Running `npm install` seems to fix this.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Does anyone know as to what causes this?

Answer (score 6):

my case was because you have the "dev" script running in the same time

Answer (score 5):

I just hit a similar error, and I had simply forgotten to run `next build` before `next export`!

Answer (score 5):

Page component naming should be unique.
So I had about.tsx with name: AboutPage and faqs.tsx with name: AboutPage as well, amending faqs.tsx to be unique fixed it :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths`. `fallback` prop was set to `false`. Changing it to `true` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running:

```
npm i --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved a similar issue by deleting 'node_modules' by running  `rm -rf node_modules` and installed the packages again.

Answer (score -1):

Incase it helps anyone else, I got the same error message when I incorrectly had capitals in the file name. E.g. `WIP-sidebar.js`.