# Next JS 13 'next build' outputs app directory app/page.js and route group pages as 0 bytes and causes 404 error in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Using the **`Next.js 13`** experimental `appDir` feature, I have been able to port all my pages from the pages directory to the app directory and everything works well in the dev environment but the issue is that I have been getting `404 error` in **production**.

I decided to troubleshoot by running `next build` locally and noticed that

- Next JS was building all the nested route group paths with the index path page `app/page.js` as 0 byte which in turn causes the 404 error for all those pages.

NOTE:

> In my `next.config.js` file, I have the experimental `appDir` flag configured while I have also deleted the `pages` directory because all the pages have now been moved to the `app` directory.

Here is a look at my `next.config.js` file:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  ...
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I have tried to look at the official documentation for possible configurations and fixes but I haven't found anything to help.

What can I do?

Thank you.

EDIT:

So on further trials,

1. I decided to eliminate the route group to test if it would actually build successfully and it did. I did that by changing `(dashboard)` folder name to `dashboard` which in turn added `'/dashboard'` to my routes which I don't want.  I need the route group in the app directory for shared layouts across the app without changing the pathname. For instance, the route group directory

Example:

- `app/(dashboard)/meeting/page.js` still has a route of `"/meeting"` instead of this directory; `app/dashboard/meeting/page.js` which now has a route of `"/dashboard/meeting"`.

2. After going through a similar issue on the `vercel/next` repository on **Github**, I discovered that the error in this particular issue occurred because the `output: "standalone"` option was set in the `next.config.js` file of the project but I do not have that option set in mine. Besides, the particular fix for this issue still noted the particular error with route groups which is what I am facing.

The baffling thing about my issue however is that the `app/page.js` meant to replace `pages/index.js` with the route `"/"` also returns 404 in production in addition with the 404 errors encountered with the route group pages.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004513/nextjs-export-gives-cannot-find-module-for-page

Comment: And maybe this more: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15880

Comment: @yousoumar. I have tried those solutions and added an exportPathMap but I am still get the 404 error pages instead of the actual pages on production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tweeted about the issue and luckily for me, Lee Robinson, the VP of Developer Experience at Vercel saw it and took a look at the repository. The issue was caused because I used `i18n` with `appDir` in the `next.config.js` file like this:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
  ...
}
```

Since the app only supports English for now and we are not planning to add any languages, I decided to remove it and all the 404 errors disappeared. Here is the updated `next.config.js` file:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  ...
}
```

If you need to support multiple languages within the `app` directory using Next JS 13, Here is a guide written [here](https://app-dir-i18n.vercel.app/en) by Vercel.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Removing the following from my `next.config.js` did the trick:

```
i18n: {
    locales: ['en'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you just repeated the already existing answer