# Next.js 13 route groups and app splitting results in 404 page not found

Tags: next.js, next.js13

### Problem

I am experimenting with Next.js 13's appDir experimental features and trying to create two separate layouts: one for marketing and one for a shop. The complete app structure is as follows:

- app

  - (marketing)

    - about

      - page.js
    - page.js
    - layout.js
  - (shop)

    - account

      - page.js
      - layout.js
  - layout.js
  - providers.js

The layout is working for the `(marketing)` and `(shop)` route groups. However, since route groups are not used for routing, the `page.js` in the `(marketing)` group should be the main page and point to the `/` route. In deployment, it refers to `/index` and `/` route gives a 404 error "This page could not be found". On localhost, everything works as expected and the `/` route points to the `(marketing)/page.js`.

### Question

How can I make it so that `<domain>/` works on deployment? I have tried looking into the documentation from Next.js but couldn't find a solution to this issue.

### Documentation

[Link to the Next.js route group documentation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes#route-groups)

### Solution

[Found the answer in this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74776667/14403486)

The issue was caused because I used i18n with appDir in the next.config.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found the answer in this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74776667/14403486)

The issue was caused because I used i18n with appDir in the next.config.js